# How SQL Server tell the database is restoring, or with unrecovery status

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore

In SQL Server, Restore has 3 kinds of status, Recovery, Unrecovery and Standby, which decide the way to deal with the "uncommitted transactions".

But what if the backup to be restore has absolutely no explicit uncommitted transactions?

I'm quite sure Recovery is still different from Unrecovery; you can't restore log backups in Recovery status and you can't read data  in Unrecovery status.

But how does SQL Server know? Is there any implicit Flag or background transaction?

Thanks for all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server restore goes through three phases:

1. load the data
2. reapply committed transactions that did not make it to disk completely.
3. undo inflight but uncommitted transactions.

The first two get executed on every restore. The UNDO phase only when you specify the `RECOVERY` option. This allows SQL Server to apply restores of log backups to this database that might contain the `COMMIT` of one or more of the in-flight transactions.

The information if the UNDO phase happened is stored with the database together with the lsn numbers necessary for further actions.

The details about all this you can read up on here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455(v=sql.105).aspx

The current state of your databases you can see with this query:

```
SELECT name,state_desc FROM sys.databases;
```